# Windows 8 Right Click Crash

Tags: windows-8

I'm running Windows 8, regrettably, and, when I right click a file in my Downloads folder, the mouse goes to busy-mode and the Downloads window then freezes.

This is incredibly infuriating. I have just tried right clicking it in the Documents folder and on my desktop, and it basically will either freeze the downloads folder or windows. I have 8gb of RAM and an i5, and my computer is not more than a month old. I haven't had such problems earlier, and I have no idea what's wrong.

EDIT: It only freezes when I right-click files, not desktop-background or webpages.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a shell extension causes it. Run [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and disable the 3rd party extension until you find the one which causes the hangs.

[image]